# Default Bios Options for ESXi Virtual Machine

Tags: vmware-esxi

Does anyone know of a way to set the default bios options of a virtual machine in ESX1 (4.1).  Every time I create a new VM, I need to go into the bios and set the Num Lock in the bios.  I was hoping to make it so that each time I created a VM, regardless of OS, the num lock was on.

Anyone know where ESXi gets the default bios options from and how to modify it?

Thanks in advance,
Rich

Answer (score 2):

Great question...

I have not tested this, but the nvram file is what keeps the bios settings. If you save off a copy of one that you have edited, and place it in your new VM folder, it *should* work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.  That file looks to be binary.  Is there anything else that is stored in there that would be machine specific?

Comment: Nope, just bios.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [What Files Make Up a Virtual Machine](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_learning_files_in_a_vm.html)
You will find all your answers here.

Also try this tool ( [VM Tweaker](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vmtweaker/)). 
Its a .vmx editor and you can change your bios using VM Tweaker plus other cool stuff.

HTH

Comment: thanks, I will take a look at VM Tweaker.  And assuming I can have a nvram file I can drop in any time I will be good, I was really hoping to find the location of the default nvram file that is probably stored somewhere in the file system of the console.

Answer (score 1):

We set numlock status in our templates -- windows machine will override BIOS setting based upon setting stored in the registry.